# При клике по 3м блокам появляется 4й

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как сделать чтоб после клика на три блока появлялся четвертый

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
```

Comment: а блоки в уме? ну тогда так: `селектором переходишь на 3 блок, вешаешь евент, показываешь четвертый` B)

Comment: <div id="1"></div><div id="2"></div><div id="3"></div><DIV ID="4"> </DIV>МОЖНО ХОТЬ ПРИМЕРНЫЙ КОД Я В JS 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Чтобы после клика на три блока появлялся четвертый

```js
let wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');

wrap.addEventListener('click', function _tmp(e) {
  let block = e.target.closest('.block');
  if( !block ) return; // return прервет функцию, если кликнули не на нужный блок.
  
  block.classList.add('clicked');
  
  if( document.querySelectorAll('.block.clicked').length === 3 ) {
    // .block.clicked без пробела: Все элементы, у которых есть оба класса
    document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = "block";
    wrap.removeEventListener('click', _tmp);
    // После завершения, обработчик клика удаляется.
  }
});
```

```css
#wrap { display: flex; }

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block.clicked {
  background-color: orange;
}

#hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block" id="hidden">4</div>
</div>
```

P.s. можно и на CSS ))

[CSS - селекторы](https://webref.ru/css#selectors)

```css
input[type="radio"] { display: none; }

#rad_1:checked + #rad_2:checked + #rad_3:checked ~ .block.hidden {
  display: block;
}

#rad_1:checked ~ label[for="rad_1"],
#rad_2:checked ~ label[for="rad_2"],
#rad_3:checked ~ label[for="rad_3"] {
  background-color: orange;
}

/***/

#wrap { display: flex; }

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <input type="radio" id="rad_1">
  <input type="radio" id="rad_2">
  <input type="radio" id="rad_3">
  
  <label class="block" for="rad_1">1</label>
  <label class="block" for="rad_2">2</label>
  <label class="block" for="rad_3">3</label>
  <label class="block hidden">4</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Можешь использовать [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)([тут](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B) про селекторы), с ним проще

```js
$('.aparent:first').children('div').click(()=>{
    $('.aparent:first').children('div:nth-child(4)').show();
});
```

```css
.aparent > div{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aparent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div style="display:none">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: В появлении 4-го фигурирует только 3-й блок... Что-то не совсем подходит под вопрос)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME а, ога, `третий блок` прочитал, вместо `все три`